# Able to access Internal endpoint of WorkerRole

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role. I have defined an input endpoint with public port 8080 and private port as 8081. I am unable to access 8080 which should redirect to private port, and I am able to access internal endpoint (private port) directly which should not be.

My worker role run method is overridden with.

```
HttpListener objHttpListener = new HttpListener();
            objHttpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8081/");
            objHttpListener.Start();
```

and I am trying to access using http//localhost:8080 which is not working.
http//localhost:8081 is working which is private port.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but... internal endpoints don't have public ports. They are internal-use only (e.g. between role instances). Maybe you meant you created an Input Endpoint?

Comment: I have given Input endpoint with public port 8080 and private port as 8081. When I am trying to access using 8080 I am unable to do. But I am able to connect using 8081. Actually when we access 8080 it should redirect to 8081 thats what my understanding is.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the port from: via the public ip address of the role, or from the role instance itself? *Please edit your question to provide these details, instead of putting them in comments.*

Comment: HttpListener objHttpListener = new HttpListener();
                objHttpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8081/");
                objHttpListener.Start(); This is in my Run method.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Are you going through the public endpoint (e.g. `myapp.cloudapp.net:8080`)? Or are you going to `localhost:8080` from within the role instance? **And please edit your question. Details should not be buried in comments.**

Comment: I have edited my question please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoint mappings are specifically from a public port to a private port. The public port is *only* accessible if you go through the public endpoint.

So, in your case, you mapped public port 8080 to private (local) port 8081. If you want to open a connection from within your role instance, you can either:

- Connect to `yourapp.cloudapp.net:8080` (which will actually connect to your VM's local port 8081)
- Connect to `localhost:8081`

You cannot connect to `localhost:8080` and and expect traffic to be routed to port 8081. The port-mapping is done via an Azure load balancer, outside of the VM (the role instance) itself.

Comment: [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-Tutorials/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Worker-Roles-Part-1) I am following this videos where he is running the worker role locally and able to redirect without deploying.